# return xml through Jquery $.ajax but through cross domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I have an application X that uses another application Y in certain cases.

X in on an Apache server, Y is on a Tomcat server.

I have a button in html file in Y which calls a JavaScript function StopApp().
This function StopApp() calls the script "StopApp.php" which is on X.

So what I did inside StopApp() is something like

```
function StopApp()
{
//USING JQUERY $.ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: pathofX + "StopApp.php",
        cache: false,
        data:"blablabla",
        dataType: "xml",

      success: function(xml)
    {

    }
  });
}
```

OK so the thing is "StopApp.php" returns an XML document, and I would like to get the values of the XML tag inside the success field, but I am not being able to do that. I know it has to do with cross domain because it's 2 different servers, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to change StopApp.php (alternatively, you can create a wrapper that calls functions from StopApp.php) and put all the logic in this file(I mean all actions the function `success` is supposed to do), you can use technique from the article [Ajax & PHP without using the XmlHttpRequest Object](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/ajax-php-xmlhttprequest-object/). Briefly, you need to create a `SCRIPT` element  with `http:://Y/StopApp.php` source and append it to document body. It's a pure JS solution, but maybe you'll find jquery plug-in that can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain calls are forbidden, you cannot circumvent this any portable way.

Btw, accept some of your older questions.